# Adding Combobox to datagridviewcell throwing index out of range exception

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

This is my code which is throwing an exception on `dgv2Cb`.
Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong ?

```
Dim dgv2Cb As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Dim str1 = "Port"
Dim rowIndex = 0

If str1 = "Port" Then
    dgv2Cb.Items.Add("1")
    dgv2Cb.Items.Add("2")

    dgv2.Rows.Add(str1)
    dgv2.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1) = dgv2Cb   'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the `.Cells(1)` code, I would venture to guess.

Are you expecting `.Cells(1)` to return `"2"`? `Cells` refers to the columns in the table, not the values in your `ComboBox`.

You may find this example code helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404353%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

**EDIT**

On a second review of your code, it looks like you are trying to add a column to the DataGridView? In that case, you should use:

```
dgv2.Columns.Add(dgv2Cb)
```